# Increase 64 digits long hexadecimal number by 1

Tags: bash, cryptography, hex

I have the following (lowest) hexadecimal number:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and would like a to increase this number by 1 until the maximum is reached:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I have so far this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for number in $( seq 1 255 )
do
  hex_representation=$( printf "%X" ${number} )
  echo "${number}: ${hex_representation}"
done
```

which outputs me almost what I want (on a small scale but its not a 64 digits long string. Any input welcome. The desired output would be:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
...
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: what is current output

Comment: until maximum is reached? All 1208925819614629174706176 values?

Comment: @domi771: I assume the loop will run a little longer :)

Comment: I would suggest Python solution

Comment: @RemusRusanu: that's only 2^80; 2^256 is a little (!) more than 3 times longer. OP: since bash is not as fast as native code, you'll need about a million million million million million million million million million times longer than the lifetime of the universe. No human _or_ computer can last that long, so you'll have to become a god first, which is offtopic for SO, but once you've acheived godhood, extremely basic programming tasks like this will be easy.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've flagged for migration to https://theism.stackexchange.com but the mod gods declined it :( More on topic: if the `echo` statement is removed then smart compilers / parsers may optimize out the counter and the program may actually finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the correct *format specifier*, along with modifiers for *leading zeros* and *field-width* (see: [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)) makes the problem quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

for number in $( seq 1 255 )
do
    printf "%064X\n" $number
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash 64bithex.sh
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000D
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
...
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FE
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FF
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you were talking about **64 bit numbers** you could do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

seq 1 18446744073709551615 | while read number
do
  hex_representation=$( printf "%016X" ${number} )
  echo "${number}: ${hex_representation}"
done
```

For this to work there were two changes necessary. Firstly, since in your version `$( seq 1 x )` will try to eagerly evaluate the expression and store the result in memory, it has to be switched out with a `while read number`, which processes each line separately.

Secondly I extended the format specifier to `"%016X"` which will pad the output with 16 zeros.

If you were actually talking about **256 bit numbers** (=64 hex digits) you could use `bc`'s arbitrary precision arithmetic to achieve this. Here's one example implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

seq 1 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 | while read number
do
  hex_representation=$( printf "%64s" "$(echo "obase=16; ${number}" | bc)" | tr ' ' '0' )
  echo "${number}: ${hex_representation}"
done
```

You could also do most of the work inside of bc itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

echo """
obase=16
x = 0
while (x < 2^256) {
    x
    x += 1
}
""" | bc | while read hexnum; do
    printf "%64s\n" "$hexnum" | tr ' ' '0'
done
```

Note that you cannot use the `%x` format specifier to convert the number to hexadecimal notation, as that would require bash to support 256bit numbers.

Instead `%64s` pads the string with spaces that are replaced with zeros by `tr ' ' '0'`.